# Style in angular6 component CSS file does not work

Tags: css, angular, angular6, shadow-dom

I am using angular6 . I have included a `bootstrap.css` file in the `src` folder. Then in my `angular.json` I include all the css files that I want

`"styles": ["../node_modules/ol/ol.css", "src/bootstrap.min.css", "src/styles.css", "../node_modules/ol-geocoder/dist/ol-geocoder.min.css", "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"]`
these are styles for : openlayers, bootstrap, the angular's default `styles.css` , geocoder module, and font-awesome. This works fine.

I put the CSS styles for general DOM elemets (header, headers etc) in the `styles.css` so they are available everywhere. This works fine.

Then I thought to include more component-specific styles to the `component.css` files. But this does not work. If I put, for example

```
.accordion .card:first-of-type form{
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

in the `styles.css`, this works fine. If I put it in the `profile.component.css`, it does not work . The component is set like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
```

Is it something with to do with shadow DOM or View Encapsulation? What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share you html file too? Just to be sure that is nothing there.

Comment: Sharing your code would be helpful to solve the issue. I have replicated your issue and it's working fine in both the cases i.e putting it in styles.css and also   putting all the styles in their respective component. So I'm assuming  there is something wrong with the code

Comment: Have you tried to put `:host ::ng-deep` before `.accordion .card:first-of-type form` ?
It overrides every attribute you are setting up.

Comment: I think Victor is right. To add some explanation: Because the accordion is a different component, your styles will not apply unless `::ng-deep` is added

Answer (score 1):

Please first confirm, Is another CSS code working in your component or not?

If another css is working then you have to mark all the properties to important into your `component.css` file as follows:

```
.accordion .card:first-of-type form {
   display: block !important;
   width: 75% !important;
   clear: both!important;
   margin-left: auto!important;
   margin-right: auto!important;
}
```

Hope this will help you!